# Execute function when closing jQuery Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

When clicking to close a Lightbox, I want that action to redirect users to a different URL. How would I write something like that? Would this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
$(“p”).click(function(){
   // Close Lightbox URL redirection
   $(this).( location ).attr("href", url);
   url = "put url here";
});
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work. This because you need to bind an event handler to the lightbox. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `lightbox`'s [**`beforeClose event`**](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight#configuration). See the following demo I created for you:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/73hutxe3/)

All you need is the following bit of jQuery:

```
$('#clickMe').featherlight('.inline', {
    beforeClose: function(event){
        // If you want to open url in other tab:
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
});
```

Here, the url is opened *in another tab*. If you want to open the url in *the same tab*, you would use:

```
location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

I hope that helps you out. Good luck!

Comment: Wow! That's amazing. What if I wanted the command to go back to the previous page? Wouldn't it be history(-1) or something like that?

Comment: @KellyL.Waters I don't think that's possible but you could try and Google it. If you think I answered your question, then consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This would work,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
$(“p”).click(function(){
   // Close Lightbox URL redirection
   url = "put url here";
   $(location).attr('href',url);
});
</body>
</html>
```

Two changes, changed `$(this)` to `$(location)` because `$(this)` there would be the `<p>` element that was clicked and not the `window` object. P.S. just a $(location) would do.

Second, moved `url = "put url here";` above the redirection code obviously to have the url before redirecting. Not doing so would throw an error as `url` would be `undefined`

To go back, you could use,

`window.history.back();`

Comment: @KellyL.Waters You're welcome! added some code for "going back" functionality as you had discussed with Jean-Paul. Edited my answer

Comment: Why are you wrapping `location` in a jquery object?

Comment: @KevinB what??? Because you have used jQuery?? And that is how you would select DOM location object using jQuery.
Anyway jQuery is not necessary, you can just use plain old vanilla javascript,
`location.href = "http://www.my-awesome-some-site.com"`

Comment: There was never a valid reason to wrap location in a jquery object, in fact it's considered an anti-pattern https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7858 $() is meant for selecting dom elements, location is not a dom element and doesn't have any of the properties you'd expect a dom element to have.